# Why is a line not quasi-isometric to a plane?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory

I really don't know how this is true, because I need to prove that there are no mappings from a line to a plane that is quasi-isometric. I think my starting point is probably wrong. Could you give a proof of the statement?

Answer (score 4):

Quasi-isometric spaces should have the same [topological ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)). But the line has two ends at infinity, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, whereas the end of the plane consists of a single connected component.